# Did Amber Heard physically abuse Johnny depp? and admit to it?

Tags: violence, celebrities

The [Daily Mail has published an article](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-7947733/Amber-Heard-admits-hitting-ex-husband-Johnny-Depp-pelting-pots-pans-tape.html)  claiming that "Amber Heard admits to 'hitting' ex-husband Johnny Depp and pelting him with pots, pans and vases".  This topic has came up repeatedly in online conversations (usually assuming that Heard did do it).

Amber Heard's wikipedia page (and the talk page) does not corroborate this claim due to the fact that the daily mail is not a reliable source and that the tape was edited by Depp's Team.

Comment: Hello Humphrey, and welcome to the site. When you have a chance please take the [tour] and see the [help]. Your question was closed because 3 users and a mod decided that the topic was about an unresolved current event, which the community here has decided is "off-topic". Please don't let this discourage you from asking more questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depp is alleging abuse by Heard in [**an ongoing lawsuit**](https://www.usatoday.com/story/life/2019/05/20/johnny-depp-v-amber-heard-depp-submits-photos-black-eye-scratches/3450310002/) filed back in March, and Heard denies this allegation. The alleged admission by Heard is on a 2015 audio recording obtained exclusively by the *Daily Mail*. Unless and until the audio is released, a lot depends on your opinion of the *Mail's* journalistic integrity.

Comment: This sounds like a comment reasoning why we should vote to close as a "current event matter".

Comment: Fair enough... I voted to close.